# Angular 7: NullInjectorError: No provider for PagerService

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, angular7

I am trying to implement pagination but It's not working. Here is my code:

**pager.service.ts:**

```
  import * as _ from 'underscore';
  @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root',
  })
export class PagerService {
  getPager(totalItems: number, currentPage: number = 1, pageSize: number = 10) {

    // calculate total pages
    let totalPages = Math.ceil(totalItems / pageSize);

    let startPage: number, endPage: number;
    if (totalPages <= 10) {
      // less than 10 total pages so show all
      startPage = 1;
      endPage = totalPages;
    } else {
      // more than 10 total pages so calculate start and end pages
      if (currentPage <= 6) {
        startPage = 1;
        endPage = 10;
      } else if (currentPage + 4 >= totalPages) {
        startPage = totalPages - 9;
        endPage = totalPages;
      } else {
        startPage = currentPage - 5;
        endPage = currentPage + 4;
      }
    }

    // calculate start and end item indexes
    let startIndex = (currentPage - 1) * pageSize;
    let endIndex = Math.min(startIndex + pageSize - 1, totalItems - 1);

    // create an array of pages to ng-repeat in the pager control
    let pages = _.range(startPage, endPage + 1);

    // return object with all pager properties required by the view
    return {
      totalItems: totalItems,
      currentPage: currentPage,
      pageSize: pageSize,
      totalPages: totalPages,
      startPage: startPage,
      endPage: endPage,
      startIndex: startIndex,
      endIndex: endIndex,
      pages: pages
    };
  }
}
```

**quick-worker-list.component.ts:**

```
import { JobService } from '@app/services';
import { PagerService } from './../../../services/pager.service';
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

import * as _ from 'underscore';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-quick-worker-list',
  templateUrl: './quick-worker-list.component.html',
  styles: []
})
export class QuickWorkerListComponent implements OnInit {
  S3ImageUrl: string;

  // array of all items to be paged
  private workerData: any[];

  // pager object
  pager: any = {};

  // paged items
  pagedItems: any[];


  constructor(private pagerService: PagerService, private jobService: JobService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.jobService.getQuickJobWorkerList(1301, 1)
      .map((response: Response) => response.json())
      .subscribe(data => {
        // set items to json response
        this.workerData = data;

        // initialize to page 1
        this.setPage(1);
      });
  }

  setPage(page: number) {
    if (page < 1 || page > this.pager.totalPages) {
      return;
    }

    // get pager object from service
    this.pager = this.pagerService.getPager(this.allItems.length, page);

    // get current page of items
    this.pagedItems = this.allItems.slice(this.pager.startIndex, this.pager.endIndex + 1);
  }
}
```

I get this error:

> QuickWorkerListComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR Error:
>   StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[QuickWorkerListComponent ->
>   PagerService]:    StaticInjectorError(Platform:
>   core)[QuickWorkerListComponent -> PagerService]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for PagerService!
>       at NullInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.get
>   (core.js:3228)
>       at resolveToken (core.js:3473)
>       at tryResolveToken (core.js:3417)
>       at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get
>   (core.js:3314)
>       at resolveToken (core.js:3473)
>       at tryResolveToken (core.js:3417)
>       at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get
>   (core.js:3314)
>       at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:19784)
>       at NgModuleRef_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgModuleRef_.get
>   (core.js:20473)
>       at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:19784)

Answer (score 38):

Following the error text, you have to import and add your `PagerService` in the **Provider** part of your `app.module.ts` file:

```
providers: [
    PagerService,
  ],
```

And don't forget to declare it as `Injectable`:

```
@Injectable()
export class PagerService {

   // ...

}
```

Answer (score 19):

Your error is related to `PagerService`, **not with the underscore**

> NullInjectorError: No provider for PagerService! at

make sure your service is registered in list of providers at app.module or has the `Injectable` declaration at top:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
```

a common example of service in angular 7 is below:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class MyService{

  constructor() { }

}
```

please [refer to documentation for Services](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for this document reference ,,, you saved my day :)

Comment: Happy to help @shruti

Answer (score 1):

Page Service or Job Service both should have Injectable attribute applied or check if you are injecting something in these services also then same applies to that also.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mono-repo:

- Register your service in the lib module's **providers** array
- Add **@Injectable()** to your service
- Add lib module in your app's AppModule, **imports** array